# Making sure each task for a given parameter is done only once in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, promise

I have a Node.JS application that takes a screenshot of a URL. Because multiple users might request the same URL at the same time, I want to make sure that at any given moment I grab a screenshot of a URL only once.

I've implemented it the following way:

```
var inProgressUrls = {};

function grabScreenshot(url) {
  var inProgress = inProgressUrls[url];
  if (inProgress) {
    return inProgress;
  }

  var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    ... grab screenshot ...

    // Once done, remove the Promise from the map.
    delete inProgressUrls[url];
  });

  inProgressUrls[url] = promise;

  return promise;
}
```

What I wonder about is whether I'm missing some concurrency issues or a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the code you provided does the job clean.

below i just tried to optimise another corner case :)

Once you call resolve(fulfill), execution goes to event loop, before the async actions of promise is invoked in next available/possible tick. Lets say while in eventloop somebody calls `grabScreenshot` with same url, i tried to optimise this below.

`delete`  will happen in async action, which does nothing but `delete url` from object.

```
var inProgressUrls = {};

function grabScreenshot(url) {
    var inProgress = inProgressUrls[url];
    if (inProgress) {
        return inProgress;
    }

    var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
        asyncScreenGrab(url,(error, data) => {
            if (!error) {
                fulfill(data);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }

            //NOT CALLING DELETE HERE TO OPTIMISE LITTLE MORE!
            //IF GRAB IS CALLED WITH SAME URL WHILE AFTER THE RESOLVE OR REJECT, BUT WE ARE AT EVENT LOOP
            //AND ASYN ACTIONS ARE NOT STARTED EXECUTING
        });
    });

    inProgressUrls[url] = promise;

    //DELETE THE STORED PROMISE EITHER FOR RESOLVE OR FOR REJECT
    promise.then(() => delete inProgressUrls[url]).catch(() => delete inProgressUrls[url])

    return promise;
}
```